# Counting a value and then showing only of its over > SQL

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to only show a row if a certain value is over 3.
This is my code.

```
SELECT cursus_id 
from cursussen 
WHERE cursus_id IN(
    SELECT cursussen.cursus_id 
    from cursussen 
    INNER JOIN inschrijvingen 
    ON cursussen.cursus_id=inschrijvingen.cursus_id 
    HAVING COUNT(cursussen.cursus_id) > 3
);
```

It just keeps giving me the same output witch is id 1.

I only want to show the cursus_id that is in my table more than 3 times.

please help me :D

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: post your table structure and desire output

Answer (score 0):

-2 already didnt know this website whas so snobby

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want this:

```
SELECT c.cursus_id, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM cursussen c
  INNER JOIN inschrijvingen i
  ON c.cursus_id = i.cursus_id
  GROUP BY c.cursus_id
  HAVING count > 3;
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT c.cursus_id AS id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM cursussen c
    INNER JOIN inschrijvingen i
    ON c.cursus_id = i.cursus_id
    GROUP BY c.cursus_id
    HAVING count > 3;
  ) t;
```